# I want to call all the spiders from one main.py file

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have build 8 crawlers in 8 .py file in spiders folder using scrapy. Now I want to create a file let say init.py that is responsible to call the crawler function upon input. How can I do that?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapycrawler.items import ScrapycrawlerItem
```

I have done this also:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({ 
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'CSV', 
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
}) 
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(spider_class)
process.start()
```

Items.py:-

```
import scrapy


class ScrapycrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    date_publish = scrapy.Field()
    date_updated = scrapy.Field()
    headline = scrapy.Field()
    maintext = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    image_url = scrapy.Field()
    article_url = scrapy.Field()
```

Hierarchy:

```
Crawler
|-scrapycrawler
|  |-__pycache__
|  | |-...
|  |-spiders
|  | |-__pycache__
|  | |-__init__.py
|  | |-crawler1.py
|  | |-crawler2.py
|  | |-crawler3.py
|  | |-crawler4.py
|  | |-crawler5.py
|  | |-crawler6.py
|  | |-crawler7.py
|  | |-crawler8.py
|  |-__init__.py
|  |-items.py
|  |-middlewares.py
|  |-pipelines.py
|  |-settings.py
|-scrapy.cfg
```

I have done this: from scrapycrawler.items import ScrapycrawlerItem
but its showing error that

```
from scrapycrawler.items import ScrapycrawlerItem 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapycrawler'
```

Comment: What’s the current working directory when you run the script? Please, inspect the contents of `sys.path`, that may give you a hint of why the module is not found.

Comment: `import sys`

`sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Darkshadow\Documents\Web Crawler\scrapycrawler')`
`from ScrapyCrawler.items import ScrapycrawlerItem`
So by providing the exact path, it's working. But its not working with the relative path.

Comment: What does `sys.path` contain before you modify it?

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can try this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("scrapy crawl <spider_name>") # run a command?
```

I ever tried this.

Comment: This is not the issue. I want to do it this way only. Using CrawlerProcess.